# Bootstrap select and django template

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

Good day everyone!

I have a strange behavior of a [Bootsrap select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and my Django template.

I have a user profile template with edit form and I added a current value of fields inside template tags like this:

```
<select id="id_bd_month" name="bd_month" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" data-size="6">
<option value="{{ request.user.profile.bd_month}}" selected="selected"></option>
<option value=“01”>January</option>
<option value=“02”>February</option>
…
```

And I have a basic script:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
```

At first when I load a page, it says "Nothing selected". But if I refreshed it again (F5), plugin works normally.

Why I have this strange effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution! As catavaran said, that was not a Django dev server issue. I just misunderstood, how to correctly use 'render' and 'value' methods. In my case solution was simple:

```
$('.selectpicker').val('{{ request.user.profile.bd_month }}');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
```

Thanks catavaran for help!

Answer (score 1):

You should set `selected` attribute to the selected `<option>` instead of empty one:

```
<select id="id_bd_month" name="bd_month" class="selectpicker" ...>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02" selected="selected">February</option>
```

Or as alternative pass the selected value to the `selectpicker()` method:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '{{ request.user.profile.bd_month}}');
```

Comment: {{ request.user.profile.bd_month }} returns me a number of birthday month. And as it said in a documentation, I can use a custom value with the 'render' method. So, as I think, selectpicker must take this number, compare with another options and add selected.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still doesn't work. I think the main reason is that I'm using standard django dev server.

Comment: No, this is not a django issue.  What is the actual value of `user.profile.bd_month`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  You need to call 'render' first and 'val' next. I fixed the answer.  BTW, quote chars in you example are `”` but should be the `"` or `'`.

Comment: If I use 'render' method, I don't need to use 'value' method, especially AFTER render. Your option won't be work at all!

Comment: Read the documentation for the selectpicker's `val` method. If you want to select option before the `render`, then set valid `selected` attribute to desired `<option>` tag.

Comment: When I remove 'selectpicker' class from my selection, it works perfect!! I think, I'm using valid option.